# summing up values from a column depending on an other column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
V1   V2  V3
AAA  x   2
AAA  x   5
AAA  y   7
BBB  y   7
BBB  x   8
BBB  y   3
```

I would like to sum up the values from V3 depending on V1
and get a data frame like that:

```
V1   V2  V3
AAA  x   7
AAA  y   7
BBB  x   8
BBB  y   10
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `aggregate(V3 ~ ., df1, sum)` or `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(V1, V2) %>% summarise(V3 = sum(V3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sqldf`. Group by `v1,v2` and do the `sum(v3)` as follow:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select V1,V2,sum(V3) from df group by V1,V2")
```

Output:

```
    V1 V2 sum(V3)
1 AAA  x       7
2 AAA  y       7
3 BBB  x       8
4 BBB  y      10
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataset

```
dt <- data.frame(V1=c("AAA","AAA","AAA","BBB","BBB","BBB"),
                 V2=c("x","x","y","y","x","y"),
                 V3=c(2,5,7,7,8,3))
dt
```

The code:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  group_by(V1,V2) %>%
  mutate( Sum= sum(V3))
```